# Push Notification Received even after Notification Centre is OFF

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created a Push Notification App, and tried sending the Push Messages when the Notification centre is ON. But now I have turned OFF the notification centre and tried pushing the messages. Still the Alert is shown for the Push Notifications and PUSH messages are received. Please help me on this.

Comment: check this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299393/keep-receiving-ios-push-notifications-after-disabling-them-in-settings-app)

Comment: Thanks @tkanzakic.. But I have added that too in my code, but what happens is when I enable it gives me the proper output in the console. But when I disable it, I dont get any output in the console. It does not display anything.